# Running a Jar file alone

Tags: java, swing

Hai
 I have an application which is designed in netbeans6.0.1 where i need to display an image as an logo.My coding is as below

```
mLogo = new JLabel();
URL lUrlLogo = getclass().getResource("/com/images/image.gif");
Image lLogoimage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(lUrlLogo);
ImageIcon licon = new ImageIcon(lLogoimage);
mLogo.setIcon(licon);
```

My code works fine when i execute it in netbeans but when I try to run my jar file which is created by netbeans in **dist** folder,it gives me an exception

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Whats the problem with my jar
Can some one help me to run my jar
Thanking u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jar file will need to include the image.

See [this tutorial](http://capturevision.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/how-to-embed-resource-files-using-netbeans/) or [this one](http://www.peterscorner.co.uk/2009/05/10/how_to_add_resources_to_intellij_idea_and_netbeans.html) for instructions for how to do that. Basically if you include the file in a source folder (with the appropriate path) it should be okay.

If you think you've already got the image there, run

```
jar tvf file.jar
```

to show the contents. Make sure everything's where you expect it to be in terms of directories.

---

EDIT: As per the comments, the problem turned out to be due to case sensitivity.

Finding resources in a jar file is *always* case-sensitive, whereas loading them from a file system is only case-sensitive if the file system is. So if your file is `image.GIF` but you're looking for `image.gif` then it'll work when you're loading from the file system in Windows, but not in the jar file.

Comment: yes i have the image inside my jar and in the location where i need it

Comment: If you call getResourceAsStream() instead of getResource(), what happens? If that returns null, then it sounds like the file *isn't* there or in the right place. Do you have it correct in terms of casing? Even if your normal file system is case-insensitive, resource lookup in the jar file won't be.

Comment: Thank u I got it its casesensitive with in extension i have changed it and its working

Answer (score 0):

And you have checked that the JAR file contains the path `"/com/images/image.gif"`?

Also, I'm not really sure about the leading slash, I always used relative paths to access resources (but I guess it should work anyways).

As an example from class `it.lapo.example.Main` I use `getClass().getResource("resources/logo.png")` and in the JAR files are this way:

```
it/lapo/example/Main.class
it/lapo/example/resources/logo.png
```

I know... not much different from your own example, but it does work... so I guess yours is quite close to being correct too.

Comment: I have used relativepaths and I found my image in specified path but still its not working